# Get the actual width and height of a MenuFlyout on UWP

Tags: uwp

Is there a way to get the actual width and height of a MenyFlyout in UWP?

I found that you can, for instance, set the `MinWidth` (very useful, by the way) like this:

```
 MenuFlyout m = this as MenuFlyout;
 Style s = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Style { TargetType = typeof(MenuFlyoutPresenter) };
 s.Setters.Add(new Setter(MenuFlyoutPresenter.MinWidthProperty, _minWidth + ""));
 m.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle = s;
```

I just cannot find a way to simply query the width and height.

Comment: You should define the height and width within the *content* control of the flyout.

Comment: I never used flyouts but there should be a way to get it's FrameworkElement and subscribe to SizeChanged event which is fired when ActualWidth or ActualHeight is changed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems we can not get the actual width and height of a MenyFlyout in UWP.

> You don't typically use a MenuFlyoutPresenter directly, either in XAML or code. Instead, you reference the MenuFlyoutPresenter type as the TargetType of the style you use for the MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle property.

For more info, see [MenuFlyoutPresenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyoutpresenter#Remarks).

We can not use the MenuFlyoutPresenter.ActualWidth property to get the actual width.

The actual width of the `MenuFlyout` is depended on the `MinWidth`, `MaxWidth` of the `MenuFlyoutPresenter` and content's width of the `MenuFlyout`.

If you want to get the actual width and height to adapt to the page, you should be able to set the `MinWidth` and `MaxWidth` of `MenuFlyoutPresenter`. That no matter the content's width changes, the `MenuFlyout` can not be too large or too small for your page.

For example:

```
<MenuFlyout x:Name="MyMenuFlyout" >
    <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
            <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="500"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
</MenuFlyout>
```